# TableView dynamic footer is not showing properly with keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with dynamic content (messages). Sometimes I have to show user `UITextField` so she could type something.

For this I created special `UIView`, and put this `UIView` in my `TableFooterView`.

If user wants to answer she has to press the button. In this case footerView will be shown:

```
if self.tableView != nil {
   if self.keyboardHeight == 0 {
      self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight - tabBarHeight - navigationBarHeight - 48 - self.keyboardHeight)
      self.scrollToBottom()
        } else {
           self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight - tabBarHeight - navigationBarHeight - self.keyboardHeight)
           self.scrollToBottom()
            }

self.scrollToBottomWithFooter()
```

`self.keyboardHeight` is the real `keyboardHeight`:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        self.showUserTextInput()
    }
}
```

`self.scrollToBottom` is just a function that scroll `TableView` to the last visible row.
`self.scrollToBottomWithFooter` doesn't scroll anything, i need this to show the footer:

```
func scrollToBottomWithFooter() {
    self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(self.tableView.convert((self.tableView.tableFooterView?.bounds)!, from: self.tableView.tableFooterView), animated: true)
}
```

So, the problem is that footer is not showing correctly in this case. It is shown properly while `self.keyboardHeight == 0` (i.e. user didn't tap on `UITextField` yet), but if keyboard is shown this footerView doesn't shown properly, there are several pixels left behind the keyboard.

`UITableView.frame` is not to blame here, because it is very easy for the user to make it right (just a little scroll by hand, and it works), but it still ugly.

What did I break here?

[image: example]

Comment: layoutIfNeeded() ?

Comment: I put self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded() in scrollToBottomWithFooter, and no, it doesn't work.

Comment: not in tableview, in footer

Comment: put self.tableView.tableFooterView?.layoutIfNeeded() in scrollToBottomWithFooter, no result :(